How to initialize object in while loop
I am trying to initialize the object till it gets successful. The code works fine, but not for the first instance / iteration. Is there any way to initialize object in while loop?
V1NamespaceList listOfns = null;
try {
    listOfns = api.listNamespace(null, true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong while fetching namespace list. Trying again ");
    while (listOfns != null)
    {
        listOfns = api.listNamespace(null, true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}

My objective is to try until listOfns object is initialized successfully. How can I achieve that?

Just write the loop outside of the try-catch-block? But if something fails, it might fail again infinitely often...

doesn't make sense to have one assignment which catches errors and a loop that doesn't. Do one or the other. Unrelated to the question, the number of arguments for the method and that they are mostly null seems odd to say the least.

Did you mean while (listOfns == null) instead of while (listOfns != null)?

I suggest adding the number of retries to the program. If the program continues to fail, you should troubleshoot what went wrong. Unless there are really special needs.
V1NamespaceList listOfNs = null;
int retryCount = 0;
final int MAX_RETRIES = 5; 
while (retryCount < MAX_RETRIES) {
    try {
        listOfNs = api.listNamespace(null, true, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null);
        if (listOfNs != null) {
            break; 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong while fetching namespace list. Trying again. Retry #" + (retryCount + 1));

    }
 retryCount++;

// can sleep for a while
 
//try {
//   Thread.sleep(1000);  
//} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
//    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  
//}
   
}

if (listOfNs == null) {
    System.out.println("Failed to fetch namespace list after " + MAX_RETRIES + " attempts.");

// TODO

}


This is where spring-retry can shine. Just configure the retryTemplate to your liking.
RetryTemplate retryTemplate = RetryTemplate.builder().infiniteRetry()
        .exponentialBackoff(Duration.ofMillis(100), 2, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).build();
String listOfNs = retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
    log.info("RetryNo: {}", context.getRetryCount());
    // return api.listNamespace(....)
    return "Hello World!";
});
log.info("Retry: {}", listOfNs);

